# How to create pipeline from postgres to parquet?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are creating a dataflow pipeline, we will read the data from postgres and write it to a parquet file. we are using the org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc to read and org.apache.beam.sdk.io.parquet package to write a file. ParquetIO.Sink allows you to write a PCollection of GenericRecord into a Parquet file (from here https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/parquet/ParquetIO.html).

this is my code so far:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
                .record("table").namespace("org.apache.avro.ipc")
                .fields()
                .name("id").type("int").noDefault()
                .name("number").type("int").noDefault()
                .name("name").type().stringType().noDefault()
                .name("password").type().stringType().noDefault()

p.apply(JdbcIO.<GenericRecord> read()
            .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                    "org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/database")
                    .withUsername("username")
                    .withPassword("password"))
                .withQuery("select * from table")
                .withRowMapper((JdbcIO.RowMapper<GenericRecord>) resultSet -> {
                        GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
                        ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
                        int columnsNumber = metadata.getColumnCount();
                        for(int i=0; i<columnsNumber; i++) {
                            String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i+1);
                            record.put(i, columnValue);
                        }
                    return record;
                })
                .withCoder(AvroCoder.of(schema)))
            .apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                    .via(ParquetIO.sink(schema).withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY))
                    .to("somethingg.parquet")
                    );
p.run()
```

and i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn@4393593c, mainOutputTag=Tag<output>, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[]}}
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:564)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$1.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:212)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.payloadForParDoLike(ParDoTranslation.java:705)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:208)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:187)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$ParDoTranslator.translate(ParDoTranslation.java:125)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:155)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getParDoPayload(ParDoTranslation.java:651)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.isSplittable(ParDoTranslation.java:666)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$6.matches(PTransformMatchers.java:269)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.visitPrimitiveTransform(Pipeline.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:665)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:251)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:458)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:258)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:208)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:170)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:313)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:299)
    at com.click.example.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:196)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1379)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1379)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:51)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Maybe you can add the conversion method that you have written so far to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty much explained in the stack trace: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema`.

`withRowMapper()` takes a serializable `RowMapper<>` functional interface. And it is being serialized and deserialized by Beam when it needs to. However in your lambda you also use the instance of `Schema` that you define outside of the lambda (closure). So when serializing your lambda Java will also have to serialize the `schema`, because it's used there. But `Schema` is not serializable, so it fails.

There are few workarounds I can think of:

- create the schema inside the lambda:

  - in this case the schema instance will not be serialized;
  - it will be created each time the lambda is called;
- serialize the schema (e.g. into a Json string) into a serializable object outside of the lambda, and then deserialize it within the lambda:

  - it's basically the same thing as above but with an extra serialization step;
  - within the lambda it will still have to be deserialized on each call;
- find/write a serializable `Schema` implementation:

  - may be not possible or hard to do;
  - will likely have less overhead as above approaches, as deserialization will only happen when creating an instance of the `RowMapper<>`;

I think it's perfectly fine to create a new instance of the schema in the lambda unless it causes problems.